# how to only target nested tag, not all other tags

Tags: jquery

Simple slideToggle on jQ Mobile app - can't get the filtering right.

```
<h4 class="trigger">Title 1<span> [ + ]</span>
<div class="formGroup">
 //form stuff
</div>

<h4 class="trigger">Title 2<span> [ + ]</span>
<div class="formGroup">
 //form stuff
</div>
```

there are about 16 groups like this, but you get the idea. The .formGroup is hidden by CSS display:none.

Using the following code, it changes the span text of every h4 > span on the page each click.

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#personnelPage", function( event ) {
    $('h4.trigger').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.formGroup').slideToggle('fast', function(){
            $('h4.trigger').find('span').text($(this).is(':visible') ? '[ - ]' : '[ + ]');
        });

    });
});
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to target the clicked `h4` element, in that case you can use a variable to hold the reference to that object and then use it in the `slideToggle` callback

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#personnelPage", function (event) {
    $('h4.trigger').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this)
        $this.next('.formGroup').slideToggle('fast', function () {
            $this.find('span').text($(this).is(':visible') ? '[ - ]' : '[ + ]');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: could you expand on the 'var $this = $(this)'? I don't have a good grasp of that and it seems I should. Thank you, worked perfectly

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign As you know `this` inside the callback refers the `h4` element, `var $this = $(this)` wraps the `h4` with jQuery and stores the reference in a variable called `$this`. Now can we use the `$this` variable inside the callback method to refer to the targeted `h4` element